# apt-get complains about untrusted packages

Tags: 13.04, apt, software-center, kubuntu, security

Since installing Kubuntu 13.04, apt-get (and all other packaging tools) complain about untrusted packages. As an example, when I try to install `ruby1.9.1-dev`:

```
# aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev  
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc{a} gcc-4.7{a} libc-dev-bin{a} libc6-dev{a} libgcc-4.7-dev{a} 
  libitm1{a} libquadmath0{a} linux-libc-dev{a} manpages-dev{a} 
  ruby1.9.1-dev 
0 packages upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 15,8 MB of archives. After unpacking 41,0 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] 
WARNING: untrusted versions of the following packages will be installed!

Untrusted packages could compromise your system's security.
You should only proceed with the installation if you are certain that
this is what you want to do.

  ruby1.9.1-dev gcc-4.7 libgcc-4.7-dev libquadmath0 gcc libc6-dev libitm1 
  linux-libc-dev manpages-dev libc-dev-bin 

Do you want to ignore this warning and proceed anyway?
To continue, enter "Yes"; to abort, enter "No":
```

I'm pretty sure `gcc` is an official package :-)

What's causing this and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try this: Cancel this operation. Run `sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update`. Then try again. If that does not work, please provide the output of `apt-cache policy gcc`.

Comment: clean & update worked. Please turn that into an answer that I can accept it.

Comment: @gertvdijk: It's a duplicate but none of those answers worked in my case. I think `apt-get clean` did the trick.